# template partial specification

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization, variable-templates

I hava the following template class like a function wrapper:

```
using MethodId = std::uint16_t;
template <typename Func>
class BaseMethod
{
public:
    BaseMethod(const Func &func, std::uint16_t method_id) : _function(func), _method_id(method_id) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args) -> decltype(_function(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return _function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    auto invoke(Args... args) -> decltype(_function(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return _function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    Func _function;
    MethodId _method_id;
};
```

with this class template, I can use like this:

```
int adder(int x, int y){return x+y;}
BaseMethod<int(*)(int, int)> foo_tempalte(adder, 0);
```

but I also want to support usage like this:

```
BaseMethod<int, int, int> bar_tempalte(adder, 0);
```

So I add a partial specification version：

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
class BaseMethod<Ret (*)(Args...)>
{
public:
    BaseMethod(Ret (*func)(Args...), std::uint16_t method_id) : _function(func), _method_id(method_id)
    {
    }

    Ret operator()(Args... args)
    {
        return _function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    Ret invoke(Args... args)
    {
        return _function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    Ret (*_function)(Args...);
    std::uint16_t _method_id;
};
```

but when I called `BaseMethod<int, int, int> bar_tempalte(adder, 0);`

the ide gave me error: `too many arguments for class template "BaseMethod"`

I wonder what is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: `<int, int, int>` does not match `<Ret (*)(Args...)>`.  `BaseMethod<int(*)(int, int)>` would call that specialization since it is a function pointer type but `BaseMethod<int, int, int>` is just 3 type paramters, that doesn't match any of your templates.

Comment: A specialization doesn't change the way the template is used. `BaseMethod` always has one argument and it doesn't matter which specializations or how many exist.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So, it is impossible to support both `BaseMethod<int(*)(int,int)>` and `BaseMethod<int, int, int>`, right？

Comment: @Xin_Wang: it's possible to write a template that would support both of those, but you'd do it considerably differently. Specialization allows you to have multiple implementations of the same interface. You're trying to provide multiple interfaces to the same implementation. At least with current C++ it seems quite unnecessary though. The compiler can deduce the type from the argument, so you can just use `BaseMethod baz_template(adder, 1);`, and the compiler will handle things from there.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to support older compilers (pre-C++17) or really, truly, absolutely need to force the user to explicitly pass template arguments, I'd just let the compiler deduce the function type from argument:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using MethodId = uint16_t;

template <typename Func>
class BaseMethod
{
public:
    BaseMethod(Func func, MethodId method_id) : _function(func), _method_id(method_id) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args)
    {
        return _function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // leaving out `invoke` since it's basically the same as operator()

private:
    Func _function;
    MethodId _method_id;
};

int adder(int x, int y){return x+y;}

int add3(int x, int y, int z) { return x + y + z; }

int main() { 
    // your original code still works:
    BaseMethod<int (*)(int, int)> foo_template(adder, 0);
    std::cout << foo_template(5, 6) << "\n";

    // But it's easier to let the compiler deduce the type:
    BaseMethod bar_template(adder, 1); 
    std::cout << bar_template(1, 2) << "\n";

    BaseMethod baz_template(add3, 2);
    std::cout << baz_template(1, 2, 3) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your careful reply :)